# All saved personal queries disappeared in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Today I loged in to BigQuery and found all of my saved personal queries disappeared. It says [No saved queries yet. Write and save a query to get started.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T89m.png)

I had a lot of large queries that I still need and I have no desire to rewrite it from scratch.

Project queries are still there, I can perform new queries and go through query history. I tried to log out and log in several times with zero effect. Have someone encountered this kind of issue before?

I would appreciate any help!

Update: I submitted the bug to Google's Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119349142

Comment: Hm...not sure what happened with your BigQuery, but I suggest that you can report this at the Issue Tracker at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers for the support to look into your project.

Comment: @JL-HN already did, thanks.

Comment: Same has happened to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue that was fixed by Google. Private queries are available again.
See for details https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119314731

Answer (score 13):

#### Edit (2022-07-18)

As user @rurp mentioned `SAVED QUERIES` is now available both below and in the left panel (see screenshot).

[image: Saved queries in BigQuery is now in Explorer]

#### Original

If anyone looking for where the `SAVED QUERIES` are and found that the **legacy UI is no longer available** and found that the **docs are outdated** (it says check in the *"left side navigation"*) this is where you can find it in 2021:

[image: Location of Saved queries in BigQuery tab of Google Cloud Platform]

Comment: It is in the worst place possible!!! I was looking for it for hours! Thansk!

Comment: Google is shockingly bad at UI sometimes.

Comment: This answer is still super helpful even in 2022! I almost freaked out that I couldn't find it when searching for a link along the top portion of the page, or along the left sidebar.

Comment: Aaaand now they're back on the left side... for now.

Comment: @rurp oh the pain...

Comment: Note that you must clear anything in the project search bar to see the saved queries folder.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the new/beta console UI. Mine have also disappeared. As a workaround, go to the old BigQuery UI [here](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com). You should see them there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Graham.
I tried switching back to the old UI when I found the issue, but it didn't help in my case, unfortunately https://www.dropbox.com/s/04m076zu32k4air/Screenshot%202018-11-12%2015.06.21.png?dl=0

Comment: Odd, works for me. Are you sure you are looking at the same project?

Comment: Yes, I checked. I can see same project queries, but it is still empty in private queries list.
Interestingly, in one of the projects I have access to one private query is still there! It is the newest query I created this past Friday, all older private queries are gone.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest update, this is where you can find saved queries:
[image]